# Separate Python web scraped data in different columns

Tags: python, excel

I tried to scrape data by using API and put those result in an CSV file. But when I open my CSV file all the data is put together in 1 column(A). Instead I want the data to be separated in different columns(A & B (and C, D, E, F etc when I want to add info)). How can I do that?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import csv

csv_file = open('/Users/katewang/Desktop/Test/scrape.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

def get_EOD_data(api_token='5cb671b0b4a790.35526238', session = None, tickers = 'AAPL', start_date = dt.datetime(2018,1,1), end_date = dt.datetime(2018,12,31)):
    symbols = tickers
    if session is None:
        session = requests.Session()

    url = 'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/%s.US' % symbols
    params = {"api_token": api_token, "from": start_date, "to": end_date}
    r = session.get(url, params = params)
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:


    cols=[0,5]
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(r.text), skipfooter = 1, parse_dates = [0], engine = 'python', na_values=['nan'], index_col = 0, usecols = cols)

    df.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)
    df.fillna(method = 'bfill', inplace = True)
    return df

def main():
    df_data = get_EOD_data()
    csv_writer.writerow([df_data])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

csv_file.close()
```

I expect to see two separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing only one column since, out of the two selected columns 0 and 5, you set column 0 to be the index when creating the dataframe. This leaves only column 5 as an actual column.

You can check for yourself by removing `index_col = 0` from the line

`df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(r.text), skipfooter = 1, parse_dates = [0], engine = 'python', na_values=['nan'], index_col = 0, usecols = cols)`

Comment: Being a bit more verbose in your response will go a long way. For now I assume you  did confirm that changing my suggested line of code, does result in a dataframe with two columns (date and adjusted_close). Thus, that would mean 'doesn't work' applies to saving to a csv. For that I suggest you use pandas' functionality to save to csv: 
```def main():
    df_data = get_EOD_data()
    df_data.to_csv('scrape_2.csv', index=False)```